# Android native code to cater to two different function signatures between apis

Tags: java, android, api

I have code for

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
```

introduced from API 24 and upwards. I want the same functionality here, for other versions less than 24. Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                                    WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                   String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                    if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);
                        return true; 
                    } else {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

My question is given the deprecated function before API 24 had the signature:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

How do I cater to devices with Android where this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using both method signatures and controlling the program flow with [annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html).

Using [@SuppressWarnings:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    .../...
}
```

Using [TargetApi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    .../...
}
```